# get name of sender in public void processPacket(Packet packet) XMPP

Tags: xmpp

I using smack XMPP for create a chat app

when I receive new message, I dont know how to get user name from this thing below

```html
 @Override
 public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
  Message message = (Message) packet;
```

I used message.getFrom() but it return me like a email address
I like it return kind of name in facebook

Answer (score 0):

Log in to Facebook and see address bar - you will see your unique id in Facebook, like "user213435445", it works the same way: when you receive facebook message from user545435345, application (Facebook site in that case) checks what "friendly name" associated with that id and show you received message from that name.

Back to XMPP - it works the same way, "email address", correctly named as **JID** - is a unique user identifier, when you receive xmpp message from user@example.com you should check what friendly name associated with it. You have the list of your contacts and their names in a **XMPP Roster**.

So, the right session flow is:

1. Log in to XMPP
2. Retrieve your roster
3. When you receive message, take the **from** and check that address present in your roster. If yes, take the friendly name of this buddy and display to user.
4. For outgoing message - when user click name of his buddy to chat, take that name and find associated **JID** in the user roster, send message to that JID.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation, thank you, it working
I used like this
 RosterEntry mRosterEntry = xmppConnection.getRoster().getEntry(userid);
  String name =  mRosterEntry.getName();